# SQL Syntax Error - INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: sql

When I run this statement within MySQL Workbench, I get a syntax error near the SELECT statement.

```
INSERT INTO 
    rare_csshop.cscart_product_features_values
        (feature_id, product_id, value, lang_code)
VALUES
    SELECT DISTINCT
    "10" As Feature, t1.product_id, CONCAT(t2.NHeigth, "\" H x ", t2.NWidth, "\" W x ", t2.NDepth, "\" D") As Dimensions, "EN" As Lang
FROM
    rare_csshop.cscart_product_descriptions AS t1, 
    rare_csshop.products AS t2
WHERE
    t1.product = t2.NName
```

The select statement runs fine on it's own.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the word `VALUES` from your query (you insert either values, OR a SELECT result).

Answer (score 2):

Take off VALUES before select statement. That should work.

```
INSERT INTO 
    rare_csshop.cscart_product_features_values
        (feature_id, product_id, value, lang_code)
    SELECT DISTINCT
    "10" As Feature, t1.product_id, CONCAT(t2.NHeigth, "\" H x ", t2.NWidth, "\" W x ", t2.NDepth, "\" D") As Dimensions, "EN" As Lang
FROM
    rare_csshop.cscart_product_descriptions AS t1, 
    rare_csshop.products AS t2
WHERE
    t1.product = t2.NName
```

I don't know why, but I came across this situation just recently. May be when we specify VALUES, it assumes only values not query results.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Just wanted to let you know you can format your code by selecting it and either pressing Ctrl+K or the `{}` button. I took care of it for you already.